# Javascript reloading iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Hi can anyone help me here I have this code that works fine reloading an iframe id but I cant seem to get it to work with a class as I would like it to reload more then 1 iframe or failing that more then 1 iframe id.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="pl" xml:lang="pl">
<head>
<title>Javascript IFrame Reload</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
// set your interval in milliseconds
var reloadInterval = 3000;
// this will run when the document is fully loaded
function init() {
 setTimeout('reload()',reloadInterval);
}
// this reloads the iframe, and triggers the next reload interval
function reload() {
 var iframe = document.getElementById('reloader');
 if (!iframe) return false;
 iframe.src = iframe.src;
 setTimeout('reload()',reloadInterval);
}
// load the init() function when the page is fully loaded
window.onload = init;
--></script>
</head>
<body>
<iframe id="reloader" width="500" height="400" src="http://www.google.com/"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use `getElementsByClassName()`, loop thru each element, reload each iframe

Comment: I don't see any class on the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use querySelectorAll (compatible with more browsers but slower and slightly different behavior) or getElementsByClassName to get a NodeList of elements you can loop through.

```
var frames = document.querySelector(".myClass");
for(var i=0; i<frames.length; ++i) {
    reload(frames[i]); // you'll have to modify your function to use a parameter
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick update I have finally achieved what I was looking for. More then 1 iframe on a page auto reloading every 5 seconds.

If anyone is interested https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Sorry thats https://jsfiddle.net/ocurf1s7/ for some reason it wont let me update the wrong link